# Generate RSA DES3 signature using phpseclib

Tags: php, rsa, phpseclib

Private key:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
Proc-Type: 4,ENCRYPTED
DEK-Info: DES-EDE3-CBC,A3CEE9AD263E2C7F
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-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

And string:

```
eyJhZ2VudCI6InBsYWFheS10ZXN0IiwidGltZXNhbHQiOjEzMjY4MTUxMDgsImFjdGlvbiI6InRlc3QiLCJ2ZXJzaW9uIjoiMS4wLjEiLCJpZCI6MX0=
```

I need generate signature to that string.
Code:

```
$xpacket = eyJhZ2VudCI6InBsYWFheS10ZXN0IiwidGltZXNhbHQiOjEzMjY4MTUxMDgsImFjdGlvbiI6InRlc3QiLCJ2ZXJzaW9uIjoiMS4wLjEiLCJpZCI6MX0=;

include('Crypt/RSA.php');
$rsa = new Crypt_RSA();
$rsa->loadKey(file_get_contents('private_rsa'), CRYPT_RSA_PUBLIC_FORMAT_PKCS1); //tryied any format there
$rsa->setSignatureMode(CRYPT_DES_MODE_3CBC);
$rsa->setPassword('my_password');
$signature = $rsa->sign($xpacket); //
echo $signature;
```

First i'd recieve this error:

```
Warning: mcrypt_generic_init() [function.mcrypt-generic-init]: Key size too large; supplied length: 26, max: 24 in /var/www/u2113183/data/www/plaaay.ru/api/Crypt/TripleDES.php on line 708
```

Than i tried to change in TripleDES.php line 255 from

```
define('CRYPT_DES_MODE', CRYPT_DES_MODE_MCRYPT);
```

to

```
define('CRYPT_DES_MODE', CRYPT_DES_MODE_INTERNAL);
```

To force internal mode. But in internal mode i recieve that error:

```
Warning: unpack() [function.unpack]: Type N: not enough input, need 4, have 2 in /var/www/u2113183/data/www/plaaay.ru/api/Crypt/DES.php on line 1047
```

Tell me please what is wrong?
Thank you.

Comment: The line of code in which you assign `$xpacket` is missing two critical things.  I think you might have error reporting turned down too low.  Please add `error_reporting(-1);` and try again.

Answer (score 0):

$rsa->setPassword() should be called before $rsa->loadKey().

Also, CRYPT_DES_MODE_3CBC isn't a valid signature mode.  The fact that the private key is encrypted key will be auto-detected by phpseclib because of the DEK-Info: DES-EDE3-CBC,A3CEE9AD263E2C7F line in the private key.  The valid parameters for $rsa->setSignatureMode() are CRYPT_RSA_SIGNATURE_PSS and CRYPT_RSA_SIGNATURE_PKCS1.